# IPB forum launches download rather than loading the page

Tags: php, forum, forums, ipb

When you visit the domain: http://www.luftwaffe-experten.org/ - there is a script downloaded, but why is this occurring? It should load a forum (/forums/)  but never actually opens/loads - why is this occurring?

I've copied the entire site via cpanels WHM account transfer process, but it fails to load - is the PHP I'm running on the server not compatible with IPB 3.4.6?

Comment: What web server are you using, such as apache or nginx? It seems your web server is not executing the script, but simply serving it as a file. It's a config problem.

Comment: Apache (CentOS6.5-64) , the server hosts several other forums, but no other IPB boards.... XenForo & vBulletin is what I'm familiar with, but not IPB - so unsure what is occurring. Thanks for the reply btw :) @BrianKeller-Heikkila

Comment: I suggest asking this question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), since this is a configuration problem, not a programming problem. The people there probably can help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI -

The problem was due to .htaccess file.

The old server was Php 4.x the new server is 5.X - so I had to comment out this line: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php`

And the forum loads perfectly now :)